# How do I configure webpack/npm to include a package in my project's source code so that I can edit it directly?

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm working on a react application that uses [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid). Serving assets through webpack, and managing dependencies via npm.

I'd like to make modifications to react-data-grid on localhost, and have those changes appear in my existing project.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Fork [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) on GitHub,
2. make modifications on that fork.
3. And with npm's ability to install packages from GitHub:

   `npm install githubname/reponame`